# GET Requests vs JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, http

Alright, I have a JavaScript doing HTTP Requests to a PHP file onto the same directory. Then it's returning it's output.

Let's say there are over 50+ people doing this request simultaneously ... will it slow down anything? Yes, this may seem like a dumb question - but sorry. :|

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simulate it? This is an impossible question without actually trying it out.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading; GET vs JS doesn't convey anything at all.

Comment: @Christian: haha, I just noticed that.  I suppose avoiding GET altogether and using JS for the answer comparison would make sense (but Dan didn't say anything about that until Codemwnci's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your backend code.

I have a php file for a scrabble type game, which simply checks if the word is valid. This does a database lookup, and responds with a true or false. It sounds like your request is doing something very similar. The way you are doing it is one of the most efficient ways, because you are only checking the results, rather than doing a full page reload.

The result is less than 20ms usually, and under load does not particularly increase that much. But my code is doing very little.

In principle though, what you are doing is fine.

Comment: riddle.php has no backend for mysql but just has ONE VARIABLE and checks to see if a word was typed correctly. Like iffiset($_GET['answer']) and if answer == "answerhere"... then output yes or no.

Comment: then it will run very very fast. The only other option you have is to store the answer (encoded) on the client side, but this is not as secure. I think your code will run easily with high volume, assuming your server is reasonable

Answer (score 1):

Potentially yes. There are some basic questions to answer:

- How long does riddle.php take to execute?
- How many simultaneous requests can your server handle?

Note that the first answer may vary if riddle.php accesses any shared resources (files, database tables) that may require locking for updates.

Answer (score 1):

#### Factors as to why this can't be answered

---

1. **Hardware Limitations** - what kind of server? how much memory? how much free resources (eg any other demanding applications running at the time)
2. **Network Limitations** - what kind of connection? how saturated is the network?
3. **Application Limitations** - what is riddle.php doing? how is the db query constructed? what does the JavaScript do with the returned result?
4. **Database Limitations** - how many concurrent connections are allowed? how many can be supported? how is the db optimized?

#### Ways to approach

---

1. Cache the php as much as you can
2. Cache previous queries as much as you can
3. Create a database connection pool (a large percentage of the time is spent in opening new connections)

Comment: I would add: **1.** Servers have a config on simultaneous connections, used to prevent DDOSes (for instance). The the server may work well with 400-500 requests, a config may limit it at 100. **2.** Consider each PHP instance has a maximum of ~30Mb/process (and a min of 11mb on my PC), that is 3gb[ram]-1gb[os]/11mb[wamo]=181 processes, at most. Those are just rudimentary calculations. Higher performance servers probably can't make it till 500+ at *the same time* without a reasonable amount of lag.

Comment: I agree, even past hardware limitations, what the configs are may limit connections.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with multiple requests at once will need server resources. It may or may not slow things down appreciably depending on how much load the server and network connection can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on several factors. Are you caching your pages? this would speed up page rendering. how fast is the actual riddle.php script, is the DB interaction that could get bogged down? what is the capacity/memory of the server you files are hosted on, what is the connection speed to that server? how much data are you rendering back? all these things figure into your answer. The best thing to do is actually write something to simulate your expected load and check your results.